# Solving integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I solve this integral:

```
Integrate[expression, x]
```

where expression is:

```
(Abs[1-x^2]-(x-1)*Log[(x-1)^2]+(x+1)*Log[(x+1)^2])^(-1/2).
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: You don't actually have an integral equation; those things have an unknown *function* within the integral sign.

Comment: @J.M. I know and you are right but do you have any idea how to solve that integral?

Comment: @James I'm sure you will have tried to run the `Integrate` command you mention, right? What happened? Did it run indefinitely? Did it return unevaluated? Did you get any errors? Consider also that some (many) integrals do not have a known symbolic form in terms of standard mathematical functions. Take a look at [Integrals That Can And Cannot Be Done](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntegralsThatCanAndCannotBeDone.html) as well.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your comment. I tried Integrate and I did not get any errors but I did get unevaluated expression.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be stuck with numeric integration in this situation. I had some good success with `NIntegrate`. You get good results using the default options, given that you don't play too much around at $\pm\infty$.  Particularly, if you are just interested in a certain definite integral, all you need is a straight forward call to `NIntegrate`,

```
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[Abs[1-x^2]-(-1+x) Log[(-1+x)^2]+(1+x) Log[(1+x)^2]], {x, 10, 100}]
(*2.26919*)

NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[Abs[1-x^2]-(-1+x) Log[(-1+x)^2]+(1+x) Log[(1+x)^2]], {x, -100, 100}]
(*9.70957*)
```

Now, if you are interested in the integration at large numbers I did encountered some floating errors popping up using the default `NIntegrate` behavior. Increasing the number of `MaxRecursions` and using a different integration method, I liked `Method -> "DoubleExponential"` in this situation, seemed to provide better convergence behavior in the numeric integration by increasing the density of quadrature points at the limits of the integration domain.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I can not use NIntegrate because I need solution in term of x. This integral is a part of equation where right hand side is C*y (C is constant). Again, thank you for answer.

Comment: Without knowing more about the application I can't offer any additional suggestions. You are most likely going to be stuck with solving the problem numerically.